# Nodejs express.json middleware trancate bignum

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, bignum

In express app, use express.json middleware to parse HTTP body data.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Logic code can get HTTP post data from rep.body object. For example, if post data is

```
'{"uid": 2^53 + 10}'

rep.body.uid will truncate uid value, it is not equal to 2^53 + 10
```

So any middleware or solution can resolve this issue?

Comment: please get someone to help you turn that into understandable English.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  sorry for that, I edit my questions again, could you help to take a look?

Comment: why are you setting the uid to a value that cannot be encoded as an intenger? JavaScript can't do integers higher than 2^53. Pick a normal  UID.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the project rewrote using node, restful API interface already existed. Looks a new API requried.

Comment: node is JavaScript and JavaScript **cannot** suppose integers over 2^53. That `'{"uid": 2^53 + 10}'` is yours, change it to `'{"uid": 1}' ` and then you have 9007199254740990 more ids to use. You can't possibly already start at an *impossibly large* number just as unique id